# How to use np.select and where on conditional rows without loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, pandas-loc

I'm trying to increase efficiency on my simulation code but cannot find a way to use np.select or np.where on assigning value to a cell in the next row without using loop.

Is this possible to change the code below to a version without loop?
Especially for i+1 Total Money cell? Others are possible but since those are all related, I stucked on this part.

```
for i in range(len(df_coupon)):
 if df_coupon.loc[i,"WL"] == 1 and df_coupon.loc[i,"Total_Money"] > 5:
  df_coupon.loc[i,"Bet_Amount"] = df_coupon.loc[i,"Total_Money"] * float(p)
  df_coupon.loc[i,"P/L"] = ((df_coupon.loc[i,"Bet_Amount"]) * (df_coupon.loc[i,"choice_odd"]-1))
  df_coupon.loc[i+1,"Total_Money"] = df_coupon.loc[i,"Total_Money"] + df_coupon.loc[i,"P/L"]
 elif df_coupon.loc[i,"WL"] == 0 and df_coupon.loc[i,"Total_Money"] > 5:
  df_coupon.loc[i,"Bet_Amount"] = df_coupon.loc[i,"Total_Money"] * float(p)
  df_coupon.loc[i,"P/L"] = ( -1 * (df_coupon.loc[i,"Bet_Amount"]))
  df_coupon.loc[i+1,"Total_Money"] = df_coupon.loc[i,"Total_Money"] + df_coupon.loc[i,"P/L"]
 elif df_coupon["Total_Money"][i] < 5:
  df_coupon.loc[i+1:len(df_coupon),"Total_Money"] = 0
  df_coupon.loc[i:,"Bet_Amount"] = df_coupon.loc[i:,"Total_Money"] * float(p)
```

Many thanks

Edit:

| choice_odd | WL | Total_Money | Bet_Amount | P/L. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.204 | 0 | 100.00 | 12.00 | -12.00 |
| 1.204 | 0 | 88.00 | 10.56 | -10.56 |
| 1.162 | 1 | 77.44 | 9.29 | 1.51 |
| 1.351 | 1 | 78.95 | 9.47 | 3.33 |
| 1.204 | 1 | 82.27 | 9.87 | 2.01 |

For the questions in the comments, this is how table looks like.

*Initial Total_Money is given by 100.

If WL = 1, which means my prediction is true, I added my bet_amount,

(total_money * p (percentage, 0.12) * (choice_odd-1)

to my total_money for the next match.

*choice_odd -1, because this is how much extra I earn.

For ex, If a bet 10$ to a match with an odd 1.5, if I win, I'll earn additional 5$ dollars; but if lost, I'll lose 10$.

If WL=0, I subtract the bet amount from the total for the next match.

If my total_money becomes less than 5, I assume I am bankrupt and finish the simulation.

Comment: Keep in mind that both `select` and `where` (which is just a 2 choice version of select) are only as good as the `cond` array(s).  People often make the mistake of thinking they are are 'iterators'.  The arguments are evaluated first, and then passed to these functions.

Comment: Why store a calculate-able aggregate like *Total_Money* in a data frame? Can you not calculate after loop? Please show sample data to illustrate what field means.

Comment: This is doable. But what's `p`?

Comment: @Parfait and Richardec I tried to answer your questions by editing. Please check again.

Comment: Please update your post with the data as plain text instead of image.

Comment: @hpaulj I actually agree with you, but those were the closest possible solutions that I could find. This loop almost takes 0.8 seconds for 3000 rows, which is too slow. There is no need to select any of them, but there should be another solution. I guess nd arrays will be similarly not useful, too.

Comment: @Corralien I made it, how can adding a table to StackOverflow be this much difficult? Incredible

Comment: @StonePY. Just copy/paste the output of `print(df.head(5).to_string(index=False))` :)

Comment: @Corralien I tried but it was looking bad enough. I guess the table I added is enough and descriptive.

Comment: Totally. I will try to answer later if I can (and understand :))

Comment: @Corralien Please let me know if you have any further question. I mean, it just an easy betting model. If I predict true, I earn a profit; if false, I lost all money that I bet.